# How do I serialize multiple items with foreach using JSON in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, json.net

I am trying to serialize objects from 2 ListViews, ListView#2 is used to display objects that are grouped while ListView#2 displays the said groups. (Selecting a group in #1 displays different set of objects in #2)

```
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + "\\data.txt"))
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem group in lV_groups.Items)
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem item in lV_items.Items)
                {
                    List<ItemSerObj> itemsObj = new List<ItemSerObj>()
                    {
                        new ItemSerObj
                        {
                            ItemName = item.SubItems[0].Text,
                            Value = item.SubItems[1].Text,
                            Quality = item.SubItems[2].Text,
                            TimeStamp = item.SubItems[3].Text
                        }
                    };

                    GroupSerObj serializeGroup = new GroupSerObj
                    {
                        GroupName = group.SubItems[0].Text,
                        UpdateRate = group.SubItems[1].Text,
                        Active = group.SubItems[2].Text,
                        Items = itemsObj

                    };


                    using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(writer, serializeGroup); //Where exception occurs.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am getting "System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot write to a closed TextWriter'" exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change it to something like this:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + "\\data.txt"))
{
    using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem group in lV_groups.Items)
        {
            List<ItemSerObj> itemsObj = new List<ItemSerObj>();

            foreach (ListViewItem item in lV_items.Items)
            {
                itemsObj.Add(
                new ItemSerObj
                {
                    ItemName = item.SubItems[0].Text,
                    Value = item.SubItems[1].Text,
                    Quality = item.SubItems[2].Text,
                    TimeStamp = item.SubItems[3].Text
                });           
            }

            GroupSerObj serializeGroup = new GroupSerObj
            {
                GroupName = group.SubItems[0].Text,
                UpdateRate = group.SubItems[1].Text,
                Active = group.SubItems[2].Text,
                Items = itemsObj
            };

            serializer.Serialize(writer, serializeGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

Each group iteration creates new List and this list is filled inside inner foreach loop.
 Later, it is added to `GroupSerObj` and serialized

Comment: I keep getting "Cannot wrrite to a closed TextWriter" exception. Same as I did in my own code.